# will-paginate issues for searchresults in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

my search results are stored in the @searchresults variable as subarrays - for example it has 3 sub-class of results books, people, carnames, such that each of this results are available in the search result as @searchresults[:books_results] etc,.

I need some help on how to apply the will_paginate for these sections (books, people etc), the railcast dealing with the paginations has a simplified version @products on which the pagination is applied compared to my @searchresults where it has kinda sub-classes of results.

what changes shld i do in controller, model?

your help is appreciated very much. thanks

Comment: do you want one pagination for each subarray or for the merged subarrays ?

Comment: I would like to know for both the sub-array cases as it would be useful to see the results based on the category. Thanks

Comment: It will more easy to understand your problem if you put your code here.